# Where is the best place to extend the functionality of built in classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few methods I am adding to Ruby's `Array` class for my Rails application.  Where is the best place to put them?

Right now I have them in config/environment.rb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

config/environment.rb isn't really the best place, since you can run into serious load ordering-problems if try to extend classes that haven't been resolved at the time environment.rb is executed.

Better to put a file into config/initializers. Any script placed there will be executed after the rails runtime is loaded.

What you could do is to create a file lib/my_extensions.rb

```
module MyExtensions
end
```

then in lib/my_extensions/array.rb :

```
module MyExtensions::Array 
  def join_with_commas
    join(", ")
  end
end
```

and in config/initializers/load_my_extensions.rb

```
class Array
  include MyExtensions::Array
end
```

This will cause MyExtensions::Array to be auto-reloaded each time you invoke a request in development mode. This is nicer than restarting your application everytime you make a change to your code.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be cleaner to add a `lib/` directory with all your extensions. Then add a line in config/environment.rb that loads the file:

```
require File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'array.rb')
```